# JQuery Navigation Menu has bottom-margin issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having an issue with a JQuery Menu providing extra 4-5 pixels on the bottom margin that I am unable to locate.  As a result there is an un-wanted bottom-margin space between the #menu div and #content div (red div):

[image]
here is the development link:
http://www.websitedevelopers.com

If someone has any idea I would greatly appreciate an insight as to what is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed "#menu"'s height to 50px instead of 57px and it solve the issue on my end. I hope this helps :)

Comment: do you mean this div? div#menu{}  the height here was never defined

Comment: It is in menu.css -> #menu -> line 160 -> height: 57px;

Comment: that was defined in #menu ul.menu li  because there was no height within div#menu{} -- well adding the height did resolve the issue, but i also have another issue with this menu.

Comment: As SKS mentioned it's in your menu.css: line 161 to be exact ;-)

Comment: Thank you for that, as I mentioned earlier, I have a more complex issue with this.  That is, if you notice horizontal lines that appear at the top of the sub menu?  This does not show up in my demo nor do these horizontal lines appear on the menu site: http://apycom.com/menus/11-black.html